# Java JFrame drawing pixel size rectangles

Tags: java, swing, colors, jframe, rectangles

I'm creating a JFrame and drawing rectangles 1x1 in size that are each a random color from RGB values from a random generator. When I run the code, the frame draws all the rectangles, but after a few seconds, the rectangles in the frame change.

The Rectangle class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
public class RandomRect extends JComponent
{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {  
      Random rand = new Random();
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      for(int y=1; y<601; y++)
      {
         for(int x=1; x<1201; x++)
         {  
            float red = rand.nextFloat();
            float green = rand.nextFloat();
            float blue = rand.nextFloat();
            Color randomColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
            Rectangle box = new Rectangle(x, y, 1, 1);
            g2.setColor(randomColor);
            g2.fill(box);
         }
      }
      System.out.println("Finished draw");
   }
}
```

"Finished draw" is printing twice.

The RectViewer class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;
public class RectViewer
{ 
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
      frame.setSize(1200,600);
      frame.setTitle("Using the Rectangle Class");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setBackground(Color.white);
      RandomRect rect = new RandomRect();
      frame.add(rect);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

I threw in a println to see if its calling the rectangle class twice and it is, but I don't know why! Can anyone help?

Comment: You will probably find that `paintComponent(Graphics)` is called several times.  Try rendering the rectangles to an image and displaying it in a label instead.

Answer (score 2):

The paintComponent() method is called whenever Swing decides that something needs to be redrawn (for example when the window is resized, deminimized, uncovered) or when you call repaint() explicitly. Therefore don't put the initialization code in paintComponent(). BTW, don't put anything that takes a long time in paintComponent(), because all the calculation you do there will be "lost"

For example, you could render the rectangles to a cached BufferedImage (as Andrew Thompson suggested) or you could save the colors in a two-dimensional array.